# Scrapy splash not returning results

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm learning scrapy (with splash) and building a spider to scrape results from js enabled pages. My spider works and does return results for js pages. However, it does not return price from this link https://www.zara.com/us/en/bejewelled-appliqu%C3%A9-dress-p07854034.html?v1=4818592&v2=733885

```
xpath used: //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_product-price", " " ))]//span/text()
```

The above xpath does return results in the browser but does not return results when invoked via scrapy. Here's my spider call

```
yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page, dont_filter=True, meta={'splash': {'args': {'wait': 5,},'endpoint': 'render.html',}})
```

Can you please help figure out why price from the site is not returned?

Thanks!

Comment: to check whether it's because of your code or configuration, you can have a screenshot of the page result from splash and check it or just check the document tree if the price is there.

Comment: oh, just took a look at your code, seems your xpath is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that price is not present at all in Splash rendered HTML output (best to see is to put your URL in Splash console in web browser on `8050` port and see it's rendered output). Start with Splash [FAQ](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#website-is-not-rendered-correctly) for when page is not rendered correctly. You will find out that in your case the solution is to [disable Private mode](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-disable-private-mode) for Splash, either via `--disable-private-mode` startup option for Docker, or by setting `splash.private_mode_enabled = false` in your LUA script. After disabling private mode, page renders correctly.

Answer (score 0):

use this for your xpath - `//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_product-price", " " ))]//span/text()` or simply `//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " )," _product-price " ))]//span/text()`

Xpath @class= predicates does not work for multiple classes (classes separated by space) like the one that you have there. To get the element, you should use contains()

Comment: I tried using the xpath you specified as well with no luck. Is there something else that could be going wrong?
//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_product-price", " " ))]//span/text()